# Banned sentences not deleting the message and banning the users

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So - I have a banned sentences in my server but somehow almost every banned sentence stopped working.. I would really be thankful for help!

Banned Sentences example:

```
  const BannedWords2 = [
    "@everyone Hello I am leaving CS:GO and giving away my skins to people who send trade offers.",
    "Hello I am leaving CS:GO and giving away my skins to people who send trade offers.",
    "For first people I will give away my 3 knifes. Don't be greedy and take few skins:",
    "Hello I am leaving CS:GO and giving away my skins",
    "For first people I will give away my 3 knifes.",
    "Don't be greedy and take few skins:",
    "@everyone Hello ! I leave cs: go and give all my inventory, the first three who send a trade - I will give a knife",
    "Hello ! I leave cs: go and give all my inventory, the first three who send a trade - I will give a knife",
    "I leave cs: go and give all my inventory",
    "the first three who send a trade - I will give a knife",
  ]
```

Code that should delete and ban the user:

```
 client.on("message", message => {
    var content = message.content.toLowerCase()
    var stringToCheck = content.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();

    
    for (var i = 0; i < BannedWords2.length; i++) {
        if (content.includes(BannedWords2[i])){  
          message.delete()
          message.member.ban()
            break
        }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Your sentences contain uppercase letters but you've forced your input to be lowercase, they'll never match.

Comment: ah alright, thanks!

Comment: While it's not specific to your issue, Since it seems you want to ban users trying to sell csgo items, I'd recommend checking for keywords instead of strict comparing entire sentances